# OpenERP email sending issue

Tags: odoo

Currently I'm working on email sending functionality of openerp version7.0 application.

Steps followed :

```
Module 'Email Templates' is installed successfully

Navigated to Settings>>Technical>>Email>>Templates

Created a new template by selecting my module 'latest_base'

Clicked on 'Add context to action button.

Clicked on preview button and no errors reported

Finally navigated to my module and clicked on send email button.
```

System throws following error.

`AttributeError: 'latest_base' object has no attribute 'message_post'`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to use .jpeg image files in your posts. That takes less space.

Comment: True Neels. I have edited my posts

Comment: please show the email template you have created

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add  below line in your class.This will take care.

**_inherit = ['mail.thread']**

Comment: I have made above chnages and It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me this is how i did it

---

1. install fetchmail module
2. install base_setup (may be this component doesn't exist in your addons)
3. configure outgoing and incoming server
4. make sure your mail address pop and smtp are enabled

---

Good luck with it.

Comment: Thanks noble_man. I have already installed  fetchmail module and base_setup. Also  test connection with incoming and outgoing server works fine. further  ensured that email address pop and smtp enabled.  **With same template email can be sent with base module without any issue. However it fails with custom module** Did you tried for custom module ??

Comment: @user3153567 not yet let me try and i'll get back to u. Best